# Cisco switch restart doesn't reload config

Tags: cisco, switch, ios

Something really strange happened to me today. I was configuring a 3750 switch and halfway through the changes I messed up. So I did what I've always done, unplug the power cable from the switch and plug it back in after a few seconds so it loads the saved startup-config. 30 minutes passed and things still weren't working as usual, so I ran **show running-config** and saw that the changes that I made previous to restarting were there! Then I ran **show startup-config** and saw that the parameters weren't there.

So, my question is, is this some kind of new feature in these switches? Do they keep the running configuration in memory in case of a hard reboot?

Comment: What is your IOS version ?

Comment: Version 12.2(58)SE2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh! The answer is really simple, the switch is part of a stack and I rebooted the switches one after the other.  The configuration was never reloaded. I feel so stupid for skipping this simple fact.

Comment: It happens to all of us... (Certainly to me...) The good news is that you will probably never make this particular mistake again ;-)